# R - Plot3D not showing axis during certain angle views

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter3d, plot3d

I'm trying to show a 3D graph from "one angle" where I should still see part of the y-axis. Currently because of the extreme angle, R automatically cuts out the y axis. However, I would like to keep this axis (labelled `HC`). I cannot find any resources on how to do this and I'm not good at coding enough to ask the right questions.

```
if (!require("plot3D")) {
install.packages("plot3D", dependencies = TRUE)
library(plot3D)
}

Data4 <- subset(Data3, OC < 1.5)
x <- Data4$OC
y <- Data4$HC
z <- Data4$DBE

pdf(file = "SAVE HERE")

scatter3D(x, y, z,clab = c("Intensity"), 
      pch = 19, cex = 0.5, resfac = 300,
      theta = 0, phi = 2.5, 
      bty = "b2", colkey = FALSE, 
      xlab = "O:C", ylab = "H:C"
      ,zlab = "DBE"
      , ticktype = "detailed"
      )
  #theta = 125, phi = 5 for corner view
dev.off()
```

And here is the image this code produces:

[image]